# broadcast receiver gets unregistered on device reboot

Tags: java, android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="" android:installLocation="internalOnly">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    >

    <receiver
        android:name=".NotifReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
  
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        </intent-filter>
        
    </activity>



</application>
```

i have a broadcast receiver which should be triggered when device is booted but it never gets triggered
when device is booted instead the whole broadcast receiver gets unregistered
.i know this has been asked multiple times before but none of the solutions seem to work

thanks in advance

edit : i am using api 19

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"` from your `<receiver>` element.

Comment: still not working. everything works just fine until you reboot the device , as i said it gets unregistered (i am using api 19 btw)